# Trouble with FileStats and searching lines for certain words

Tags: java

I am having a bit of trouble with the FileStats class to show how many  lines contain the text being asked for by the user.  I keep getting the incorrect answer to how many lines contain the text. I believe my code is ignoring punctuation (e.g. it won't detect the.) and upper-case variations like (The).

For Example if a file contains 5268 lines, and 1137 of those lines contain the word "the", my code returns output saying it only contains 1032 of those lines contain the word "the".

Any help would be appreciated Thank you. Code is Below

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //creating object for scanner class
    System.out.println("Enter a filename");
    String file_name = input.nextLine(); //asking user to enter a file name


    int word_line_count =0, line_count=0; //count variables for counting the line count and word occurance count
    String search_word = input.nextLine(); //asking user to enter a search_Word
    File f = new File(file_name); //Creating File Descriptor for reading input file
    String[] words_sentence = null; //creating string which stores the all words in a line
    FileReader file_object = new FileReader(file_name); // Creating File Reader object
    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(file_object); //Creating BufferedReader object
    String sentence;

    while((sentence=buffer.readLine())!=null) //Reading Content from the file till the end of file
    {

        if (sentence.contains(search_word))
        {
            word_line_count++;
        }

        line_count++; //increment line count for every while loop iteration
    }

    System.out.println(file_name + " has " + line_count + " lines"); //printing the line count

    System.out.println("Enter some text");

    System.out.println( word_line_count+ " line(s) contain "+"\""+search_word+"\""); //printing the number of lines contains the given word
    file_object.close(); //closing file object
}
}
```

Comment: *"asking user to enter a search_Word"* You forgot to actually *ask* the user, you know, by printing something like `Enter search word`.

Comment: What is the point of `File f`? You never use it.

Comment: *"1137 of those lines contain the word "the", my code returns output saying it only contains 1032 of those lines contain the word "the""* Are you sure the other 105 lines don't just contain the word "The"? The [`equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) method is case-sensitive. Call [`equalsIgnoreCase()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase-java.lang.String-) if you want `the` and `The` to compare equal.

Comment: Is any of the new code case sensitive? Sorry i uploaded the not updated one

Comment: Yes, [`contains(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains-java.lang.CharSequence-) is case-sensitive. Any method whose javadoc doesn't specifically say that it's case-insensitive, is case-sensitive.